# Does an HTTP tunnel take place on the same socket than CONNECT?

Tags: sockets, https

I'm trying to implement an HTTP proxy for learning and debug purpose.

The support of plain HTTP transactions was pretty straightforward to implement and now I'm looking to implement support for SSL/TLS tunnels.

From RFC 7230:

> A "tunnel" acts as a blind relay between two connections without
>   changing the messages. Once active, a tunnel is not considered a party
>   to the HTTP communication, though the tunnel might have been initiated
>   by an HTTP request.

It's not very clear whether I shall build the TLS socket from the socket on which the HTTP CONNECT transaction took place. I assume it is the case, since HTTP is stateless, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: people downvoted a little to easy here for my taste, as if the RFC's are all that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connects to an HTTP proxy, `CONNECT` is used to have the proxy establish a persistent TCP connection with the target TCP server.  Then the proxy blindly passes data as-is back and forth between the two TCP connections until either the client or server disconnects, then the proxy disconnects the other party. This allows the client to send data to the server and vice versa, such as TLS packets.  This is important so the TLS server can verify the client's identity during the TLS handshake.

So, to answer your question - yes, the client must establish a TLS session with the target server using the same TCP socket that it used to issue the `CONNECT` request on.  Once the `CONNECT` request has succeeded, the client can treat the existing TCP connection as if it had connected to the server directly.  The proxy is transparent at that point, neither party needs to care that it is present.